# Jersey 2.5 as filter http status 404

Tags: java, rest, servlet-filters, jersey-2.0

I have deployed a Jersey 2.5 application as a filter, but I get an HTTP Status 404 - Not Found error when accessing this (or any resource) url:

localhost:8080/[appname]/rest/users/new

This url worked previously when the app was deployed as a servlet. If I convert the 'filter' tags to 'servlet' tags, the url works again.

There is no exception on startup, and previously set breakpoints are no longer being fired. It is as if the resource classes aren't being found. Any idea what could be going wrong?

My web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>jerseywebapp</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.[pkg].resources</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature, 
            org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.MvcFeature, 
            org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature, 
            org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/views</param-value>
    </init-param>
     <!-- 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     -->
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jerseywebapp</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Limitations of Jersey JSP MVC Templates

Jersey web applications that want to use JSP templating support should be registered as Servlet filters rather than Servlets in the application's web.xml. The web.xml-less deployment style introduced in Servlet 3.0 is not supported at the moment for web applications that require use of Jersey MVC templating support.

Comment: At the risk of abandoning an unanswered question, I have to report that I am running Jersey as a Servlet, and everything is working fine.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or more information on this issue, @broadbear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, changing the `service` tags to `filter` tags works the same, with the caveat that `@Path("...")` annotations will *not* assume to be matched within the context of the `<url-pattern>`. You'll have to add the pattern to the path annotation manually.

For example, with this XML in `web.xml`:

```
...
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jerseywebapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

With this configuration, you can expect to get a match with this path annotation at `/rest/test/ping`:

```
@Path("test")
public class Test {

   @GET
   @Path("ping")
   public Response getPing() {
      ....
   }
```

Now, if we switch to using `filter` tags:

```
...
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jerseywebapp</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Note that to still hit our endpoint at `/rest/test/ping`, we need to change our class `@Path` annotation from **"test"** to **"rest/test"**:

```
@Path("rest/test")
public class Test {

   @GET
   @Path("ping")
   public Response getPing() {
      ....
   }
```

Comment: Everything was working while deployed as a servlet, so I never bothered getting the filter deployment to work. I've accepted the answer as it looks relevant and is potentially good information.